# is there anyway of getting a values index in an iterable when using functools.reduce in python

Tags: python, reduce, functools

I have a function that would benefit from using functools.reduce it would act something like this

```py
import functools

def add(total, val, max_index, index):
    if index > max_index:
        return total
    else:
        return total + val

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
functools.reduce(functools.partial(add, max_index=5), arr, 0)
```

how do I pass the index of the `val` in the `arr` into the function or is it just not possible
I thought about using a global variable to track the index but of course would much rather not

by the way my function is meant to be used for an array a lot larger than an array of len 8

Comment: You seem to want to get the sum of the first n elements of an iteratable object. Try using `sum(itertools.islice(iterable, max_index))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always pass `enumerate(arr)` which transforms any iterable of elements X_i into another of elements `(i,X_i)`.

Then the function would need to unpack the "value" it received (which is now a 2-tuple) into index and value.

Example:

```
import functools

def add(total, index_val, max_index):
    index, val = index_val
    if index > max_index:
        return total
    else:
        return total + val

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
res = functools.reduce(functools.partial(add, max_index=5), enumerate(arr,0), 0)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `reduce` function is removed from global namespace to functools and general instruction is to use list comprehension instead. Using list-comprehensions I would do it like this:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
max_index = 5
# 0-based index
print( sum([val for index, val in enumerate(arr,0) if index<=max_index]) )
# output is 21
```

Comment: Correction: map is still in the global namespace, and only reduce has been removed.

Comment: @MechanicPig  - Corrected - thanks!